# Receiving 'undefined' when using getBalance from web3

Tags: web3js, ether, nodejs, ropsten, infura

I am trying to fetch the balance of an address by web3 and node from Ropsten network with the commands below:

```
var Test = require('web3')
var url = 'https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/...'
var web3 = new Test(url)
var address = 'A Public Address'
web3.eth.getBalance(address, (err, bal) => {balance = bal})
balance`
```

The result is :

```
undefined
```

It was working and all of sudden this happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getBalance` is asynchronous, so you can't assign a variable in the callback and expect that variable to be set in synchronous code after that.

You can move any code that requires the balance into the callback of `getBalance`, e.g.:

```js
web3.eth.getBalance(address, (err, bal) => {
  if (err) {
    // Do something with the error
    return console.error(err);
  }

  console.log(bal.toString());
})
```

You can read more about (async) callbacks [here](https://javascript.info/callbacks).